# meaning of "that" in the sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> something that happen that you can't control

What does this sentence mean?And,what does the second "that" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "that" is referring to the "something"

> something that happen**s** that you can't control
>   ***something*** *that happens, and that* ***is something*** *you can't control*

An example of what that *something* might be is *falling in love*.

> *falling in love* happens, and you can't control *falling in love*

Comment: So,the functionalities of the two "that"s are the same?

Comment: @zzzgoo Yes, both "that"s are relative pronouns, but they are at a different syntactic level or hierarchy. The referent of the first "that" is "something", while the referent of the second "that" is "something that happens".